# can't update json column using Laravel eloquent model

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to test an update to an Eloquent model...

```
 /** @test */
  public function updates_to_json_fields_are_logged()
    {
      $data = json_encode(["json_key" => "old_value"]);
      $individual = Individual::factory()->create([
        "information" => $data
      ]);
      json_decode($individual->information)->json_key = "new_value";
      $individual->save();
      
      echo(var_dump($individual));

      $this->assertTrue(false);

  }
```

`information` is a json column.

When I log `$individual` after saving it, the value of `"information->json_key"` is still `"old_value"`.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You code did exactly what you wrote. assigned `"new_value"` on the new object returned by `json_decode`. no changes happened on the object stored in `$individual`

Comment: @N69S. how do I change the origin object?

Comment: i added an answer below, did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the $individual object without fancy assign

```
/** @test */
  public function updates_to_json_fields_are_logged()
    {
      $data = json_encode(["json_key" => "old_value"]);
      $individual = Individual::factory()->create([
        "information" => $data
      ]);
      $decodedInformation = json_decode($individual->information);
      $decodedInformation->json_key = "new_value";
      $individual->information = json_encode($decodedInformation);
      $individual->save();
      
      echo(var_dump($individual));

      $this->assertTrue(false);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't change original `$individual` object, but the result of `json_decode()`.

Comment: @m m. how do I change the original object then?